# Android SDK, Unfortunteley "My app" has stopped

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I'm new to mobile development and I'm making my first app using Android SDK. Unfortunately, my app stops running every time I try to run it.

Here is my code for the main.

```
package com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;


import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.B1;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.B2;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.B3;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.B4;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.Opp;
//import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.T1;
//import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.T2;
//import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.T3;
//import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.T4;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.month;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);
    //TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(T1);
    //TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(T2);
    //TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(T3);
    //TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(T4);
    Button butt1 = (Button) findViewById(B1);
    Button butt2 = (Button) findViewById(B2);
    Button butt3 = (Button) findViewById(B3);
    Button butt4 = (Button) findViewById(B4);

    butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            EveMan mb = new EveMan("UCLA", 5, "October", 7, "00");
            Intent myIntent;
            myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MA2.class);
            TextView opp = (TextView) findViewById(Opp);
            opp.setText(mb.getOpp());
            TextView Month = (TextView) findViewById(month);
            Month.setText(mb.getMonth());
            TextView day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
            day.setText(mb.getDay());
            TextView hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
            hour.setText(mb.getHour());
            TextView min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
            min.setText(mb.getMin());
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    butt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            EveMan wb = new EveMan("UC Irvine", 6, "October", 7, "00");
            Intent myIntent1;
            myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MA2.class);
            TextView opp = (TextView) findViewById(Opp);
            opp.setText(wb.getOpp());
            TextView Month = (TextView) findViewById(month);
            Month.setText(wb.getMonth());
            TextView day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
            day.setText(wb.getDay());
            TextView hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
            hour.setText(wb.getHour());
            TextView min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
            min.setText(wb.getMin());
            startActivity(myIntent1);
        }
    });
    butt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            EveMan mv = new EveMan("UC Davis", 10, "October", 7, "00");
            Intent myIntent2;
            myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MA2.class);
            TextView opp = (TextView) findViewById(Opp);
            opp.setText(mv.getOpp());
            TextView Month = (TextView) findViewById(month);
            Month.setText(mv.getMonth());
            TextView day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
            day.setText(mv.getDay());
            TextView hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
            hour.setText(mv.getHour());
            TextView min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
            min.setText(mv.getMin());
            startActivity(myIntent2);
        }
    });
    butt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            EveMan wv = new EveMan("UC Santa Cruz", 11, "October", 7, "00");
            Intent myIntent3;
            myIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MA2.class);
            TextView opp = (TextView) findViewById(Opp);
            opp.setText(wv.getOpp());
            TextView Month = (TextView) findViewById(month);
            Month.setText(wv.getMonth());
            TextView day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
            day.setText(wv.getDay());
            TextView hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
            hour.setText(wv.getHour());
            TextView min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
            min.setText(wv.getMin());
            startActivity(myIntent3);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my LogCat

```
03-17 15:47:11.435    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-17 15:47:12.286    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.189ms for cause Alloc
03-17 15:47:12.302    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 18MB/20MB, paused 2.991ms total 14.771ms
03-17 15:47:12.318    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25(1024B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 1.560ms total 11.349ms
03-17 15:47:12.334    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 1.600ms total 12.087ms
03-17 15:47:12.337    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 180MB allocation
03-17 15:47:12.355    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 18MB/22MB, paused 2.024ms total 17.136ms
03-17 15:47:12.359    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 189007516 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 45MB until OOM"
03-17 15:47:12.359    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
03-17 15:47:12.360    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-17 15:47:12.361    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp, PID: 2301
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 189007516 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 45MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 03-17 15:52:12.722    2301-2301/com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp I/Process﹕         Sending signal. PID: 2301 SIG: 9
```

My manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MA2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ma2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.MA2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MA2.java

```
package com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.id.be;
import static com.example.jayveeengracio.icsapp.R.layout.events;


public class MA2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(events);
        Button tickets = (Button) findViewById(be);

        tickets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SN);
                tex.setText("YES");
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ma2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gobows"
    android:id="@+id/Page1">

    <TextView android:text="@string/mbball"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/T1"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/mvball"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/T2"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_below="@+id/T1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/wbball"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/T3"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_below="@+id/T2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/wvball"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/T4"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_below="@+id/T3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tix"
        android:id="@+id/B1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/T1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/T1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/T1"
        android:background="@drawable/bball"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tix"
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        android:background="@drawable/bball"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/T2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tix"
        android:id="@+id/B3"
        android:background="@drawable/vball"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/T3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/tix"
        android:id="@+id/B4"
        android:background="@drawable/vball"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/T4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/page2"
    android:background="@drawable/gobows">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/opp"
        android:id="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#ff00e500"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="@string/mon"
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ff00e500"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="@string/day"
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:background="#ff00e500"
        android:layout_below="@+id/month"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/month"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/month"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/getix"
        android:id="@+id/be"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Opp"
        android:background="#ff0f330f"
        android:textColor="#ff70ff70" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/hour"
        android:id="@+id/hour"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Opp"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/min"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Opp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hour"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hour"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="@string/sn"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:id="@+id/SN"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="@string/number"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions helps, thank you!

Comment: show your xml line 62

Comment: show your codes of `MA2.java`. Log shows `MA2.class` is not loaded right way.

Comment: I wouldn't comment out imports. If you no longer use them let the ide clean it up for you. What will likely happen is you'll use them again, they'll be auto-inserted then you'll have dups.

Comment: What happens if you remove the static import on the button's id and use `R.id.be`? BTW, I've never seen it done that way; not that it can't be, just never seen it.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your layout xml file. please show your layout file where you have your views like button

Comment: It looks like `B1` in `Button butt1 = (Button) findViewById(B1);` is a variable that's not assigned to a resource.  Try replacing all of your findViewById's with `Button butt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1);` etc.

Comment: Have you set some ridiculously large image in your xml, as a background, perhaps? You seem to be allocating quite a lot of memory ...

Answer (score 0):

You have an OutOfMemoryError:

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 189007516 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 45MB until OOM"
```

Which seems to be caused by some code in your main xml file:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
```

This leads me to suggest, that the error is caused by trying to load huge image files.
You might want to ensure that your images don't take up more than a few MB.

To test this, you could remove all images from your xml, and take a look if the error persists, or not.